# Is there a way to get code-hints for gtk3 and python working on aptana?

Tags: python, aptana, pydev, gtk3

My situation is Aptana eclipse plug-in installed and working properly.

If I `from gi.repository import Gtk` the code completion I'm used to from `import gtk` is gone.  Any solutions or is it just a bug?

My interim solution is keeping an `import gtk\ngtk.` in a clipboard manager and dropping it in when I need hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is!
You should add gi to the forced builtins and you'll get a code completion:

Go to the Window->Preferences, PyDev->Interpreter python section and add gi to the "Forced builtin" tab for *each* interpreter you would like to use Gtk3.

More about this:
http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html

Comment: You Sir, are awesome :) I had just tried gi.repository with no success... I was so close and so far to solution :)
You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

> `from gi.repository import Gtk`

is not same like

> `import gtk`

With the statement "

> `from gi.repository import Gtk`

your are importing Gtk 3. With

> `import gtk`

your are importing Gtk 2.

I would say that you code completion doesn't know Gtk 3.

maybe useful:

Tutorial for Gtk 3 http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/index.html

http://live.gnome.org/PyGObject

Comment: I'm aware of the difference from gtk2 to gtk3.  I was wondering if the code completion in Aptana for that module had a solution or not.